# Unable to create default project for Jenkins extensions

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I just opened the terminal and executed the below command which will create a default project structure for Jenkins Plugin development. But I had build failure with below error message.I'm a newbie for Jenkins plugins world.

**Command:**

> mvn hpi:create

**Exception:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:2.7:create (default-cli) on
>   project standalone-pom: Unimplemented! [ERROR] hpi:create is obsolete.
>
> Instead use: [ERROR] ==== [ERROR] mvn archetype:generate
>   -Dfilter=io.jenkins.archetypes: [ERROR] ==== [ERROR] [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Any leads...

Answer (score 0):

The hpi:create mojo appears to be deprecated in favor of using an archetype. The error message has been improved in the [master branch](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-hpi-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/maven/plugins/hpi/CreateMojo.java#L27) but the version you are using isn't as helpful.

Take a look at the [Create a new Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-CreatingaNewPlugin) section of the [Plugin Tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) for more recent instructions.